# SQL Query: Group Concat Children Elements With Parent

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, wordpress, parent-child

I am trying to query a WordPress database to export a list of posts and their content. I have everything working but can't figure out how to include the attached images. I'm not sure how to associate the children with the parent within the same table.

The parent identifier is in a column called ID, and the child identifier is in a column called post_parent. The value I am trying to concatenate is in a column called guid, which contains the full URL to the image (exactly what I need).

wp_posts Table Structure:

```
ID   post_parent   guid          post_type
1     0             http://...    attachment
2     1             http://...    attachment
3     1             http://...    attachment
4     1             http://...    attachment
```

Here is my query as it stands:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
post_title
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-year' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "Year"
,(SELECT group_concat(wap_terms.name separator ', ') 
FROM wap_terms
INNER JOIN wap_term_taxonomy ON wap_terms.term_id = wap_term_taxonomy.term_id
INNER JOIN wap_term_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wap_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE taxonomy= 'car-manufacturer' AND wap_posts.ID = wpr.object_id
) AS "Manufacturer"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-model' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "Model"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-trim' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "Trim"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-vin' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "VIN"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-odometer' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "Odometer"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-price' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "Price"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-extcolor' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "Exterior Color"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-intcolor' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "Interior Color"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-transmission' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "Transmission"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-engine' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "Engine"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-fuel' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "Fuel Type"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-drivetrain' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "Drivetrain"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-doors' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "car-doors"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wap_postmeta WHERE wap_postmeta.meta_key = 'car-stockno' AND wap_postmeta.post_id = wap_posts.ID) AS "Stock #"
,(SELECT group_concat(wap_terms.name separator ', ') 
FROM wap_terms
INNER JOIN wap_term_taxonomy ON wap_terms.term_id = wap_term_taxonomy.term_id
INNER JOIN wap_term_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wap_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE taxonomy= 'car-feature' AND wap_posts.ID = wpr.object_id
) AS "Features"
,(SELECT group_concat(wap_terms.name separator ', ') 
FROM wap_terms
INNER JOIN wap_term_taxonomy ON wap_terms.term_id = wap_term_taxonomy.term_id
INNER JOIN wap_term_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wap_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE taxonomy= 'car-body-type' AND wap_posts.ID = wpr.object_id
) AS "Body Type"

-- MY PROBLEM STARTS HERE
,(SELECT group_concat(wap_posts.guid separator ', ') 
FROM wap_posts
WHERE wap_posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND wap_posts.post_parent = wap_posts.ID
) AS "Images"
-- MY PROBLEM ENDS HERE

FROM wap_posts
WHERE post_type = 'vehicle' AND post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY
post_title
```

I realize this returns NULL because the attachment's post_parent never matches it's own ID. I just don't know how to tell the query to match the post_parent value with the parent's ID rather than it's own ID.

Hopefully I have posted enough information, let me know if there is any other data I should include. Thanks for reading!

Best Regards,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

you can do a `left join` to the same table to produce the required result (assuming that not every post would have attachment)

```
select     p.Id,group_concat(c.guid separator ', ') guids 
from wap_posts p
left join wap_posts c on (c.post_parent = p.id)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7522/1/0

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me wrap my head around using variables. Still trying to figure out how to make it work with the big query I posted above, though.

Comment: I get a SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) error. It doesn't seem to like being inside of a subselect; I put it where my previous SELECT statement was, leaving the subselect brackets and AS "Images" at the end. Sorry for my naivety, and if there is a related reference you recommend I'll gladly check it out. I'm a-learnun! :)